# Accessing files on FTP server through custom VPN from app deployed on App Engine Flex: doable?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vpn, app-engine-flexible

I have the following use case:

1. Application is deployed on App Engine Flex environment.
2. Application fetches data from an FTP server on API request.
3. FTP  server can only be accessed through a custom VPN.

Can I access the FTP server from an App Engine Flex environment? If so, what would I need?

Apologies if this is not clear, I am not a network/devOps person.

Comment: Have a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-shared-vpc. Do you have FTP server and custom VPN server installed on Compute Engine instances?

Comment: No, the FTP server and custom VPN server are all on premise.

Comment: Is your application able to connect to your custom VPN?

Comment: No, I haven't developed the app yet. I am just analyzing the feasibility.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution, you can connect your on-premises network and application deployed to App Engine Flex via [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview):

> **Cloud VPN securely connects your [peer](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#peer-definition) network to your Google
>   Cloud (GCP) [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs) through an
>   [IPsec](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) [VPN](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) connection**. Traffic traveling between the two
>   networks is encrypted by one VPN gateway, then decrypted by the other
>   VPN gateway. This protects your data as it travels over the internet.
>   You can also connect two instances of Cloud VPN to each other.

[App Engine Flexible Environment is based on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python) and consequently can connect to your remote network via Cloud VPNs. As described in the documentation [Configuring your App with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml), you can specify network settings in your `app.yaml` configuration file:

> ... **app in App Engine is configured using an app.yaml file, that
>   contains** CPU, memory, **network** and disk resources, scaling, and other
>   general settings including environment variables.